# Speech Precognition and Do some action with hardware

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, robotics

I am good programmer but I am new for Robotics. I want to make small project which will recognize my speech and my light on and off.

Please provide me some reference library for all things.

What kind of hardware I need for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Robotics I would diffiently recommend you to check out the Arduino device. The Arduino device is an easily programmable circut board. You can read more at http://www.arduino.cc

Regarding Speech recogniztion you could use Microsoft Speech recogniztion software, which allows you to communicate with your app via. An library. Find out how to install it here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306537

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I got good idea from Microsoft inbuilt library. I need help of doing some stuff Example If I will say "Light Off" then Light should be off with my room. So What kind of hardware do I require?

Comment: You can use the Arduino device for that aswell. It accepts serial inputs, therefore if for example you send '1', through COM3 it will output 'HIGH' power to an power increaser, which is then connected to your lamp or light.

Answer (score 0):

The example given in your comments of saying "Lights Off" to turn a light off in a room sounds more like home automation than robotics. I would look at the open source project called [Mayhem on CodePlex](http://mayhem.codeplex.com/).  This applications makes it easy to wire events with actions using plug in modules and was developed by Microsoft Labs.  Modules are easy to develop and it comes out of the box with an event module for speech recognition.  You just configure an event for speech recognition by telling the app what phrase you are looking for like "Lights Off". There is already an [extensive list of add-on modules for Mayhem](http://makemayhem.com/Packages/All), and one of them is a reaction module for Insteon devices. This [add-on module](http://makemayhem.com/Packages/Insteon.Mayhem) lets you control INSTEON-brand lighting and home automation devices.  There is also a [PhidgetsModule](http://makemayhem.com/Packages/PhidgetModules) which allows you to control Phidgets, a set of "plug and play" building blocks for low cost USB sensing and control from your PC.  Microsoft had a contest to encourage developers to create new add-on modules and you can [see a demonstration here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=drvwok9mYbM) of a module called [RemoteCommand](http://remotecommand.codeplex.com/) which shows how you could use speech recognition over a telephone to remotely control your home.